# jQuery .bind only working on first element

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a jQuery function that will allow me to add, edit, and delete articles on my site. Right now, I am trying to write the delete functionality. Basically, when the delete button is clicked, it will send the id of that specific article to a php script via ajax request. It gets the article ID from the ID attribute of the article element.

My problem is, that when the Delete button is clicked I get an alert box with the article ID on the first article, but not on the rest.

Here is my code:

HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="contentLeft">
            <?php
            foreach($data->blogPosts as $post){
            ?>
                <article id="<?php print $post->ID; ?>" class="article">
                    <div id="options">
                        <div id="edit"><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" id="editButton"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> Edit</i></a></div>
                        <div id="delete"><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" id="deleteButton"><i class="fa fa-trash-o">Delete</a></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="articleTitle"><?php echo $post->Title; ?></div>
                    <div id="content">
                    <?php echo $post->Content; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="date"><?php echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime($post->Date)); ?></div>
                </article>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#deleteButton").bind('click', function(){
        var id = $("article").closest("article").attr("id");
        alert(id);
});
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: ID's must be unique. Therefore, only the first one on the page can be identified by said id.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense, actually. Is there a way I can loop through the article elements?

Comment: Yes, however, there's little reason to. `$(".delete a")` should work. the code inside the handler will not work though, you'll want to select the article based on the click element, using `this`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I got it working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a given document `id`s should be unique; no more than one element should have the same ID. Please change your id's to classes and change your js accordingly:

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" href="#"> ....
```

**JS**

```
$(".deleteButton").bind('click',...
```

Comment: Can't believe it was something that simple... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add only one element with the same id.
Probably you should change id to class:

```
<div class="delete"><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" class="deleteButton"><i class="fa fa-trash-o">Delete</a></i></div>
```

and in your js code:

```
$(".deleteButton").bind(...)
```